# Using Quotation Marks in Android Toast

Tags: android, toast

I just need to know how to surround a portion of a toast in quotes. I have done some searching on the net, but I don't see any clear instructions on how to do this. In the toast below, for example, I want to surround the variable gameTitleInput in quotes:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "New entry " +gameTitleInput+ " added to database!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Any help/advice is appreciated!

Mike 
        }

Comment: Putting a special character into a string is called "escaping." If you use that keyword in your searches, you'll likely find much more information.

Comment: Thanks! Knowing that helps a great deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape the quotes with a backslash:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "New entry \"" +gameTitleInput+ "\" added to database!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with: `"New entry \"" +gameTitleInput+ "\" added to database!"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  Toast.makeText(this, "New entry \"" +gameTitleInput+ "\" added to database!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Well it's matter of time , Every one who will answer to the question will have the exact same ans. Don't you agree with that? And for your good ans see I also have voted up your ans.